# Flex setting stage.mouseChildren to false prevents the use of busy cursor

Tags: apache-flex, cursor

Im trying to disable mouse click and present the busy cursor externally from the UIComponent. im doing this:

```
protected function setBusyCursor() : void {

        const stage:Stage = mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage;
        if (stage){
            stage.mouseChildren = false;
        }
        CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
    }
```

this indeed disable mouse click but the cursor appear is the regular pointer (not the busy one). any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manage to do it with this:

```
protected function setBusyCursor() : void 
    {   
        var i : int = 0;
        var uiComponent : UIComponent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parent.getChildAt(i);
        while (uiComponent != null){
            uiComponent.mouseChildren = false;
            uiComponent.cursorManager.setBusyCursor();
            i+=1;
            if ( FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parent.getChildAt(i) is UIComponent) {
                uiComponent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parent.getChildAt(i);
            }
            else {
                uiComponent = null;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function removeBusyCursor() : void {
        var i : int = 0;
        var uiComponent : UIComponent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parent.getChildAt(i);           
        while (uiComponent != null){
            uiComponent.cursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
            uiComponent.mouseChildren = true;
            i+=1;
            if ( FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parent.getChildAt(i) is UIComponent) {
                uiComponent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parent.getChildAt(i);
            }
            else {
                uiComponent = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

it disable all the mouse clicks in the screen and put the busy cursor.

Answer (score 0):

All code needed, i tested for 4.5.1 flex framework, work perfect. Use:

```
protected function setBusyCursor() : void 
{       
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.mouseChildren = false;
    CursorManager.removeAllCursors();
    CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ilya, but it doesn't disable the mouse click (the cursor is busy though), im with flash builder 4.5. and doing this not on the uicomponent but from a controler externally, any thoughts?

Comment: this also doesnt work. do you know maybe why it works when im doing it on the stage and not like this?

Comment: this doesnt work as well (disables the mouse but no busy cursor), thanks for the suggestions.